# How to print function name with function pointer in Linux kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel

I'm reading the Linux kernel code. Some functions are called by function pointer. I want to know the call sequence of all these functions, so I've tried to print the function. But I haven't figured out how to make it.

Here is my code:

```
for (fn = initcall_levels[level]; fn < initcall_levels[level+1]; fn++) {
    //printk("xhl -- %pF \n", fn);
    do_one_initcall(*fn);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kernel's `printk()` supports special `%p` format specifiers:

> ## Symbols/Function Pointers
>
> ```
>     %pF     versatile_init+0x0/0x110
>     %pf     versatile_init
>     %pS     versatile_init+0x0/0x110
>     %pSR    versatile_init+0x9/0x110
>             (with __builtin_extract_return_addr() translation)
>     %ps     versatile_init
>     %pB     prev_fn_of_versatile_init+0x88/0x88
> ```

See https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/printk-formats.txt for full list.

For your example, setting the `initcall_debug=1` kernel cmdline option might be a better way, than adding `printk()` manually.

Comment: @teddyxiong53: If the answer works for you, consider to [accept it](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).